# Jasmine functional tests with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jasmine

Could someone explain the correct way to integrate the Jasmine test runner in a React app (without adding Karma)? I am deploying my test cases to a TV and running the standalone spec runner on the set. I had to inline and transpile the JS, which is where I run into trouble. I ended up manually concatenating the jasmine.js jasmine-html.js, and boot.js files into a jasmine-all.js file and inserting a call to define jasmineRequire like so:

```
jasmineRequire = getJasmineRequireObj();
```

This was right before the inlining of jasmine-html.js. I then added a snippet in my React root component to load the whole thing like so:

```
  componentDidMount() {
   import('./jasmine/lib/jasmine-3.2.1/jasmine-all')
     .then(() => {return import('./spec/MyAppSpec');});
  }
```

I'm using a dynamic import here to guarantee the order of execution. The idea is to allow the app to load, then load the test runner, then finally load the **functional** tests, which exercise the application as a whole. These tests will send key events and input to the app as if it were an end user.

I know there a less kludgy way to do this but I couldn't figure it out. I want to do this the right way so that I can properly include any spec-helper files, which I am currently importing directly in my spec files. Any guidance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure what's the point of doing imports in `componentDidMount`. It's a spec that should instantiate a component, not in the opposite way. *I'm using a dynamic import here to guarantee the order of execution* - you cannot. Components may change after they were mounted. They may be async, and there will be no promise to chain. You may end with clumsy setTimeouts here and there in specs. I'd suggest to not use tools for jobs they weren't intended for. Some e2e framework like Testcafe would be more suitable. If you want to test how the whole React app works, just test it as any other JS app

Comment: I'm not instantiating the components from the specs. These are functional tests meant to be run after the entire app loads as they test the app as a single black-box unit.

Comment: Also I need to ensure the specs don't execute before the test runner loads. That is the intention behind my use of dynamic imports. I import the test runner then load/run my specs. I've updated my question to further emphasize that these are functional tests if that wasn't clear from the title.

Comment: Seems like I understood the case correctly. As I said, you chose wrong tool. E2e frameworks have specific functionality for blackbox testing, e.g. wait for DOM element to appear, etc, regardless of async processes under the hood. Jasmine has functionality for unit tests only. It's possible to make e2e tests work there but you will need to write this functionality from scratch, i.e. write a bunch of helper functions that are dedicated to E2E (Protractor E2E framework is based on Jasmine, IIRC).

Comment: Thanks, I understand what you're saying. To clarify, I've looked into various e2e frameworks and unfortunately many of these present challenges for the platform I'm developing on. I am targeting Tizen 2.x TVs where I have limited access to. Many of these tools would require root access and/or add'l binaries to facilitate instrumentation. I'm using Jasmine as a poor-man's roll your own automation, something I had done in the past on Android.

Comment: I've used Jasmine for functional tests in the past but never with a React web-app. I'm thinking there is better a way to properly include the test runner via npm dependency without the kludge I'm using. I've basically downloaded the stand-alone runner . files and concatenated them together but is there a better recipe for running the test runner on top of my react app?

Comment: E2E frameworks don't necessary require to run Node on same device you test, otherwise you wouldn't be able to test iOS, for example. Seems like you're reinventing the wheel. I'd suggest to check Testcafe. You run `testcafe remote` locally and then connect to specified URL on your device. As for functional (e2e) tests in Jasmine, it's no different in React. The idea with loading Jasmine in componentDidMount feels very wrong. I'd expect that you do `render(<App/>, rootElement)` in Jasmine test , throw in a considerable timeout and assert DOM. I'll provide an example but I consider it dead end.

Answer (score 3):

There is no guarantee that an application reached its stable state in root component `componentDidMount`, even if all asynchronous operations like API requests are stubbed. It should be done in the opposite way, i.e. the application is initialized inside tests and waited to be stable.

There is no built-in functionality for functional/E2E testing in Jasmine, it has to be written from scratch.

It's something like:

```
async function waitForElement(selector, parent = document, timeout = 2000) {
  let isTimeout;

  setTimeout(() => {
    isTimeout = true;
  }, timeout);

  let el;
  while (!(el = parent.querySelector(selector))) {
    if (isTimeout) throw new Error('timeout');
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 50));
  }

  return el;
}

const root = document.getElementById('root');
beforeEach(() => {
  ReactDOM.render(<App/>, root);
});

afterEach(() => {
  ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(root);
});

it('should have foo child', async () => {
  const foo = await waitForElement('div.foo', root, 5000);
  expect($(foo).text()).toContain('foo text');
});
```

Tests are promise-based and rely on waiting for results to appear in DOM because this is expected to happen asynchronously.

`waitForElement` is provided for reference only because it won't be enough for real-world E2E testing; there will a need for advanced selectors that are not supported by `querySelector` (can be enhanced with jQuery) or custom predicate function.

This is the functionality that E2E frameworks like [TestCafe](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/) and Protractor are expected to have, the availability of this functionality differs them from frameworks intended for unit testing. E.g. TestCafe has [reusable and chainable selectors](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/selecting-page-elements/selectors/) that can be implicitly processed in places that expect an element.

Comment: Thank you, I see where you are going here. I was thinking my immediate problem was loading jasmine properly via import but you are indicating that I would eventually hit synchronization issues as certain elements are not guaranteed available when `componentDidMount()` fires. I'll look into testcafe as it sounds like it gets around my immediate limitation of running web driver on the device.

Comment: *I would eventually hit synchronization issues as certain elements are not guaranteed available* - that's correct, that's the problem blackbox tests are supposed to address.

Comment: It'll still be a struggling to figure out how to get testcafe to automate my react TV app as it's not the same as launching a browser. The "page" I need to load is the index.js in the context of the apps bundle. I somehow have to trick the TV into launching an app rather than loading a page. Does testcafe have a test html I can bundle which calls home to the runner?

Comment: Following here for remote testing: https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/recipes/testing-on-remote-computers-and-mobile-devices.html It looks like I can have my remote device open a URL on the local network but then that would exit my `app` and run the web-browser. I need to load/test pages in my app, not run a browser which may be a bit of a challenge.

Comment: Does the app support redirection with `location.href`? You will likely need some dummy app to run tests any way. The scenario you're describing seems to be non-trivial for any framework.

Comment: Yeah, using location.href opens the web browser as well. I'm going to continue tinkering with this. Thanks for your tips! :)

Comment: Just forgot about https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-testing-library . It's not tied to testing framework and can be used with Jasmine. Since it's focused on functional testing, it already contains several helpers like waitForElement.

Comment: Just now getting back to this thread. Thanks for the additional tip! I'll check out react-testing-library as well.